# How to Query Data for Certain Result

Tags: sql

okay here is my data set

```
Event_ID |  WorkerNumberID
3        |  Worker1
3        |  Worker2
3        |  Worker2
3        |  Worker3
5        |  Worker4
5        |  Worker5
3        |  Null
5        |  Null
```

I want my query to return the below. Even though eventID 3 has 2 'worker2's I still only want it to count that as 1 non null item because they are the same.

```
Event_ID | WorkerNumberIDCount (a count of not null items)
 3       |  3
 5       |  2
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Event_ID,COUNT(DISTINCT WorkerNumberID) AS WorkerNumberIDCount 
FROM TableName
WHERE  WorkerNumberID IS NOT NULL
Group By Event_ID
```

Comment: thank you!!!! i don't know why i couldn't think of that. here is what i ended up doing. i ended up getting an error with the sum(workernumberID) because it is a varchar however, the count( distinct , workernumberID) was able to pull the data the way i needed it. 


'select EVENT_id, count(distinct WorkerNumberID) from tableName
where WorkerNumberID is not null
group by event_id'

Comment: @SteveShort thanks for info , Since `WorkerNumberID` seems to be ID then I assuming that it is Numeric DataType  , Any way I will updated Ans According